# mysql slow log : administrator command: Init DB

Tags: mysql

today, i found some slow query logged by slow log.

But  i don't know some record mean in the log : "#administrator command: Init DB;"

i'm use mysql-5.6 and php mysqli Extension.

I had search on Google about “init db”, but there is no clear answer；

```
# Query_time: 0.780922  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1475161137;
# administrator command: Init DB;
# User@Host: wpt[wpt] @  [10.237.220.226]  Id: 4099347882
# Query_time: 0.782442  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1475161137;
# administrator command: Init DB;
# User@Host: wpt[wpt] @  [10.143.43.138]  Id: 4099347906
# Query_time: 0.781526  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1475161137;
# administrator command: Init DB;
# User@Host: wpt[wpt] @  [10.143.43.138]  Id: 4099347908
# Query_time: 0.781560  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1475161137;
# administrator command: Init DB;
# User@Host: wpt[wpt] @  [10.237.220.226]  Id: 4099132169
# Query_time: 0.785297  Lock_time: 0.000296 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1475161137;
```